# Trying to follow a tutorial in python and I keep getting this error - istart = _int(start) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have gone line by line in my code and found a few mistakes but not any that fixed this issue.  I have gone over the original code from the turorial line by line and couldn't find a difference up to the place I am at.  I searched google and stackoverflow and the answers for the "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" usually involve the code having a variable similar to a function name, which I don't have.  I ran it through pycharm's debugger and I didn't understand the response.  It highlighted *istart = int(start)*, which isn't in my code.  Is this an issue with the code interacting with pycharm?  Any help would be appreciated.

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\isaia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Projects\Space Shooter Tutorial\pygame tutorial - space invaders.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\isaia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Projects\Space Shooter Tutorial\pygame tutorial - space invaders.py", line 115, in main
    enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100, random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"])))
  File "C:\Users\isaia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 210, in randrange
    istart = _int(start)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**Code**

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import time
pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 750
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Shooter Tutorial")

# Load images
RED_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_red_small.png"))
GREEN_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_green_small.png"))
BLUE_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_blue_small.png"))

# Player ship
YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_ship_yellow.png"))

# Lasers
RED_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_red.png"))
GREEN_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_green.png"))
BLUE_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_blue.png"))
YELLOW_LASER = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "pixel_laser_yellow.png"))

# Background
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "background-black.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Ship:
        def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.health = health
                self.ship_img = None
                self.laser_img = None
                self.lasers = []
                self.cool_down_counter = 0

        def draw(self, window):
                window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))

        def get_width(self):
                return self.ship_img.get_width()

        def get_height(self):
                return self.ship_img.get_height()

class Player(Ship):
        def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
                super().__init__(x, y, health)
                self.ship_img = YELLOW_SPACE_SHIP
                self.laser_img = YELLOW_LASER
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
                self.max_health = health
                
class Enemy(Ship):
        COLOR_MAP = {
                "red": (RED_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                "green": (GREEN_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                "blue": (BLUE_SPACE_SHIP, BLUE_LASER)
                }
        def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
                super().__init__(x, y, health)
                self.ship_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOR_MAP[color]
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

        def move(self, vel):
                self.y += vel
                
                
def main():
        run = True
        FPS = 60
        level = 0
        lives = 5
        main_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)

        enemies = []
        wave_length = 5
        enemy_vel = 1

        player_vel = 5
        
        player = Player(int(round(WIDTH/2)) - 25, 650)

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        def redraw_window():
                WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))
                # draw text
                lives_label = main_font.render(f"Lives: {lives}", 1, (255, 255, 255))
                level_label = main_font.render(f"Level: {level}", 1, (255, 255, 255))

                WIN.blit(level_label, (10, 10))
                WIN.blit(lives_label, (WIDTH - lives_label.get_width() - 10, 10))

                for enemy in enemies:
                        enemy.draw(WIN)

                player.draw(WIN)
         
                pygame.display.update()
                
        while run:
                clock.tick(FPS)
                redraw_window()

                if len(enemies) == 0:
                        level += 1
                        wave_length += 5
                        for i in range(wave_length):
                                enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100, random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"])))
                                enemies.append(enemy)

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                run = False

                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x - player_vel > 0: # left
                        player.x -= player_vel
                if keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x + player_vel + player.get_width() < WIDTH: # right
                        player.x += player_vel
                if keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.y - player_vel > 0: # up
                        player.y -= player_vel
                if keys[pygame.K_s] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.y + player_vel + player.get_height() < HEIGHT: # down
                        player.y += player_vel

                for enemy in enemies:
                        enemy.move(enemy_vel)



main()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The assignment to `enemy` has messed-up parentheses.  Each call to `random.randrange()` should have exactly two parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Python. Just to clear up @jasonharper statement:
`enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100, random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"])))`                                      .
Should be
 `enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]))`

Comment: Thanks.  I had it like that before and I kept getting a syntax error on the next line.  - Got it.  I was missing the parenthesis at the end of WIDTH.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.randrange()` takes 2 parameters, you gave it 4. To fix it, add closing parentheses for the first call to `randrange` on the problematic line, and remove the last parenthesis.

```
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH - 100),
              random.randrange(-1500, -100),
              random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]))
```

(Formatted for clarity.)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.  Do you know why it gave the "istart = _int(start) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".  The istart = _int(start) portion is throwing me off.

Comment: That's because `randrange` is defined like `def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, _int=int)`: [check out the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/66c899661902edc18df96a5c3f22639310700491/Lib/random.py#L200). The last parameter is the offender: `_int=int` is a performance hack, because local variables are faster than global variables. It is used to convert the other arguments to integers.